# let $T:V_1 \rightarrow V_2$ be a linear transformation (and an isomorphism) given by $PAP^{-1}$. Find suitable basis so T=A.

Tags: linear-algebra

So our linear operator is given by $PAP^{-1}$ where $P$ and $A$ are invertible.

I know that the change of base matrix is given by $S^{-1}DS$ where $D$ represents our transformation with respect to our original basis and  $S$ is the change base matrix. I have a feeling that to make our operator $T$ equal to $A$, we have to change base matrix by $P$.  Is that right? If our original basis is given by $(v_1,...,v_n)$, which basis should we change into so that our change of base matrix is $P$?

Edit: Should the new basis be ($Pv_1,...,Pv_n)$? If so, why?

Edit 2: What would the base chnage matrix would be if our new basis is ($Pv_1,...,Pv_n)$? (my question basically boils down to this)

Comment: Note that for any transformation of the form $PAP^{-1}$, the domain and codomain must be identical. That is, your definition makes no sense in the case that $V_1 \neq V_2$

Comment: lets assume the are identical

Comment: Also, changing basis does not change the transformation $T$, but is **does** change the matrix of $T$ relative to that basis.  Presumably then, you're looking for a basis $\mathcal B$ such that *the matrix of $T$ relative to $\mathcal B$ is $A$*, which means that $T:V \to V$ is a linear map, but $A$ is a square matrix.

Comment: If $V$ is any vector space besides the usual $\Bbb R^n$, then with $T = PAP^{-1}$ the operator $P$ is no longer a "change of basis matrix".  Rather, $P: \Bbb R^n \to V$ is a **choice of basis** transformation.

Comment: okay, thank you. do you have any suggestions as to how to find the base change matrix identified as $B'=BR$ Where  $B$ is equal to $(v_1,..,v_n)$ and $B'$ is equal to $(Pv_1,...,Pv_n)$ and I am trying to find $R$. ? Your comments cleared up all my confusion expect that part

Comment: Sure, I'll write up an answer about that.

Comment: Thank you, its very late here. I will make sure to accept your answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $A$ is the matrix of the transformation $T:V \to V$ relative to the basis $\mathcal B = \{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$; that is, $A = [T]_{\mathcal B}$.  We would like to find the matrix of $T$ relative to the new basis, $\mathcal B' = \{Pv_1,\dots,Pv_n\}$, where $P:V \to V$ is invertible.

To incorporate $P$ into our calculations, we'll need to represent it as a matrix.

We can find $[P]_{\mathcal B}$ as follows.  Let's say that we know what $P$ does to $v_k$, and that
$$
Pv_k = p_{1k} v_1 + \cdots + p_{nk} v_n.
$$
In other words, the coordinate vector of $Pv_k$ relative to $\mathcal B$ is given by
$$
[Pv_k]_{\mathcal B} = (p_{1k}, \dots , p_{nk})^T.
$$
Let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ denote the columns of the identity matrix.  We note that for a matrix $M$, $Me_k$ is the $k$th column of $M$. We have
$$
[P]_\mathcal B\,e_k = [P]_{\mathcal B}[v_k]_{\mathcal B} = [Pv_k]_{\mathcal B} = (p_{1k}, \dots , p_{nk})^T
$$
In other words, the coefficients $p_{ij}$ are the entries of $[P]_{\mathcal B}$.

Now, let's start by finding the change of basis matrix from $\mathcal B'$ to $\mathcal B$. First, a review what a change of basis matrix does.  We say that $M$ is a change of basis from $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ to $\{w_1,\dots,w_n\}$ if we have
$$
M(a_1,\dots,a_n)^T = (b_1,\dots,b_n)^T \iff a_1v_1 + \cdots + a_n v_n = b_1 w_1 + \cdots + b_n w_n.
$$
In other words, $M$ takes in our "$v$ coordinates" and produces "$w$ coordinates".  Symbolically, our $M$ should satisfy $M[x]_{\mathcal B'} = [x]_{\mathcal B}$ for any $x \in V$. To see what the $k$th column of $M$ is, let's see what $M$ does to $e_k$.  We have
$$
Me_k = M[Pv_k]_{\mathcal B'} = [Pv_k]_{\mathcal B} = (p_{1k}, \dots , p_{nk})^T,
$$
but this looks familiar.  In fact, $[P]_{\mathcal B}$ is exactly the change of basis matrix that we were looking for.

By the way, let's use $[I]_{\mathcal B' \to \mathcal B}$ to denote the change of basis matrix from $\mathcal B'$ to $\mathcal B$.

For the reverse change of basis, we're just doing the opposite thing.  So, 
$$
[I]_{\mathcal B \to \mathcal B'} = [I]^{-1}_{\mathcal B' \to \mathcal B}
$$
and as we established, $[I]_{\mathcal B' \to \mathcal B} = [P]_{\mathcal B}$.

We're finally ready for the answer. $[T]_{\mathcal B'}$ is supposed to take a vector $[x]_{\mathcal B'}$ and spit out $[T(x)]_{\mathcal B'}$.  We could produce this result from $[x]_{\mathcal B'}$ with the following sequence of operations:
$$
[T(x)]_{\mathcal B'} = [I]_{\mathcal B \to B'} [T(x)]_{\mathcal B} = 
[I]_{\mathcal B \to B'} [T]_{\mathcal B}[x]_{\mathcal B} = 
[I]_{\mathcal B \to B'} [T]_{\mathcal B}[I]_{\mathcal B' \to B}[x]_{\mathcal B'}.
$$
In other words, we have
$$
[T]_{\mathcal B'} = 
[I]_{\mathcal B \to B'} [T]_{\mathcal B}[I]_{\mathcal B' \to B} =
[P]_{\mathcal B}^{-1} A[P]_{\mathcal B}.
$$